# intialiizing react app using constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering a simple react component.

Can anyone explain why I have to new up the AppInitializer, `new AppInitializer().run();` instead of just `AppInitializer.run();`

```
class AppInitializer {
run() {
    render(
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={ App } >
                <IndexRoute component={ Home } />
            </Route>
            <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
        </Router>
        , document.getElementById('app')
    );
   }
}

new AppInitializer().run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`run` is an non static function of the AppInitializer class. In order to invoke it you must create instance of the class.

The following code:

```
new AppInitializer().run();
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var a = new AppInitializer();
a.run();
```